Google recaptcha v2 is not showing in angular app
I Used google reCaptcha V2 in angualr application.
I followed all the instructions which are mentioned on official website : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-captcha And also placed the Google recaptcha v2 key.
But Unable to render captcha div.

Unfortunately, in some cases, captcha not renders until you import 'NgxCaptchaModule' in the following parent module of the component where you are using recaptcha.
